# POSIX - understanding the non blocking send implementation

Tags: linux, network-programming, posix, send, nonblocking

I would like to understand better the non blocking `send` to socket implementation.

Given that I use a non-blocking socket, and send data out using char buffer "buf" and the `send` returns with `EAGAIN` error. Could I assume that the "buf" content was copied to an internal buffer in the POSIX framework/network stack and I can use the "buf" to send new data to the socket or the `EAGAIN` means that the data in "buf" will be copied later and so that "buf" memory shouldn't be changed?

I searched a lot about this, but didn't find an unambiguous answer to this question.

For `aio_write` I found in the man pages the following note:

> The buffer area being written out must not be accessed
>          during the operation or undefined results may occur.  The memory
>          areas involved must remain valid.

but for non-blocking I didn't find something similar.

Thanks.

Comment: The E in EAGAIN stands for error. EGAIN is an error. It means there was no (not even partial) success in sending anything. You should try AGAIN with the same arguments.

Answer (score 4):

It's important to understand that non-blocking I/O and asynchronous I/O are different models.

With non-blocking I/O, each `send` or `recv` happens immediately, but only if it can be accomplished without blocking the calling process. That means, for `send`, there is room in the kernel socket buffers for at least some of the data being sent. And for `recv`, there are at least some data bytes to be received. In these cases, the call will "succeed", returning the number of bytes sent or received, respectively. Otherwise, the call will fail, returning `-1` and setting `errno` to `EAGAIN` (and nothing will have been sent or received or copied to or from your buffer).

On the other hand, `aio_write` (and `aio_read`) are truly asynchronous: an I/O operation is enqueued with these calls, and will proceed even if no progress can be made immediately. The kernel will continue to monitor and "shepherd" the request while your process is doing other things. So, for `aio_write`, the operation could complete immediately, or it could complete at some later time. In either case, you would either have to poll for completion, or use the `sigevent` mechanism to be notified of completion -- as explained in the `aio(7)` and `sigevent(7)` manual pages.

The caution about modifying the buffer after executing `aio_write` is because you have enqueued a write operation but the kernel has not necessarily yet consumed your buffer, so if you were to modify its contents, it's indeterminate whether the kernel would consume the old contents or the new.

The same caution *would* (and does) apply to modifying the buffer given to an an ordinary `send` (whether blocking or non-blocking) *while* the `send` call is in operation. But, since the ordinary `send` is synchronous with respect to the sending thread, the only way you could do that is by modifying it from another thread while the `send` operation is executing in the original thread.

Answer (score 2):

The man page for [send(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendmsg.2.html) states:

> EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK
>
> The socket is marked nonblocking and the requested operation
>                 would block.  POSIX.1-2001 allows either error to be returned
>                 for this case, and does not require these constants to have
>                 the same value, so a portable application should check for
>                 both possibilities.

Given that you are using non-blocking I/O the way to interpret this is:
**The receiver on the other end of the socket is busy and not ready to receive data.**  Therefore, you can assume `buf`'s contents have not been used (and not copied into the kernel).

FYI: You can prevent this error by doing a [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) on the socket's file descriptor to determine when it's ready to receive data.

Comment: The way to interpret this is that the local send buffer is full, which in turn means the remote receive buffer is full, which in turn means that the receiver is reading slower than you are sending.

Answer (score 1):

> ... returns with EAGAIN error. Could I assume that the "buf" content was copied to an internal buffer

No, the error means nothing was copied, and you need to retry the whole buffer.

Remember you should also be checking the non-error return values as it might successfully write *part* of your buffer.

> I searched a lot about this, but didn't find an unambiguous answer to this question

OK, I agree the man page isn't very explicit about this. Instead let's look at the interface, and think about what could possibly happen when we call it:

```
ssize_t result = send(sockfd, buf, len, 0);

if (result < 0) {
    /* we have an error, so examine errno */
    return;
}
if (result == len) {
    /* we sent the whole buffer and can reuse buf at will */
}
else {
    /* 0 <= result < len, so we sent some of buf, but not all.
     * It's not an error but we need to keep buf[result..len] for later
     */
}
```

Those three branches cover every eventuality - it can't return anything else *not* covered by them.

It either sends something or nothing, and if it sends something, we need to know how many bytes.

It either succeeds (returns >= 0) or fails, and if it fails, we can't *also* know how many bytes were sent.

So, the only sane way to write this interface is for no bytes to be sent if there's an error - otherwise we're left in an indeterminate state (we can't figure out whether some, none or all of buf need to be re-tried).

---

I think there's another misconception here:

> Could I assume that the "buf" content was copied to an internal buffer in the POSIX framework/network stack

That's what happens when the send *succeeds*. Returning success doesn't mean your data has been received, or even actually sent: it *only* means the OS has taken responsibility for delivering it.

So in your suggestion, there would be no difference between success and failure.

Answer (score 0):

> Could I assume that the "buf" content was copied to an internal buffer in the POSIX framework/network stack

Certainly not. That's why it is telling you to try it again. Nothing was transferred anywhere.

> I can use the "buf" to send new data to the socket

No.

> or the EAGAIN means that the data in "buf" will be copied later

It will never be copied until *you* retry the send.

> and so that "buf" memory shouldn't be changed?

You can do whatever you like to it, but if you want to retry you'd better not change it first.

> I searched a lot about this but didn't find an unambiguous answer to this question.

Hard to believe. Your searching should have started with the *man* page for `send()`.

> For `aio_write` I found in the man pages the following note:

Irrelevant. That wording is because the data hasn't been written yet, but will be when the async I/O gets around to it. Nothing to do with non-blocking mode.

Comment: Consider editing this to improve the tone. It's on the abrasive side.

Comment: On the one hand, an abrasive tone is a pretty efficient way of communicating cultural norms such as _we expect you read the manpage, and say what else you researched and why it didn't help_

Comment: On the other hand, OP did at least some of that, and my local copy of the Linux `send` manpage isn't very informative. The [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html) description is slightly better, and maybe EJP's local system is better still.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Consider stating exactly where and how this is 'on the abrasive side', instead of merely making vague insinuations of no actual value. Or providing your own answer so we can criticitize its form instead of its content.